# Typescript from data object to reduced interface

Tags: typescript, interface

**Problem description**

My-current-data:

```
{
  "field1": "value",
  "field2": 3,
  "field3": true,
  "extraField": "toRemove"
}
```

I define the next interface:

```
export interface MyInterface {
  field1: string;
  field2: number;
  field3: boolean;
}
```

**Target**

I need to transform or cast my-current-data to MyInterface (remove *extraField* )

**Avoid the following solutions**

- delete **myData.extraField**;
- **.map()** operator

Comment: Doesn't that object already satisfy the conditions for the interface? It's a superset of the interface, so anything that expects that interface will be able to properly handle `myData` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
type SomeType = Omit<typeof someObject, "extraField">;
```

`Omit` typedef can be found in typescript 2.8 changelog

Comment: however you probably meant something else

Comment: lodash.omit(data, "extraField")